# Pandas : Cannot select row from dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe

```
                Word  1_gram-Probability
0             ('A',)            0.001461
1            ('45',)            0.000730
```

now i just want to select the row where `Word` is 45. i tried

```
print(simple_df.loc[simple_df['Word']=='45'])
```

but i get

```
Empty DataFrame
```

what am i missing? Is this the correct way of accessing the row? I also tried `('45',)` as the value but that did not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have the literal string value `"('45',)"` in the cell of your dataframe. You must select it exactly so.

```
simple_df.loc[simple_df['Word']=="('45',)"]
```

Comment: agreed `print(pd.DataFrame({'Word': [('A',), ('45',)], '1_gram-Probability': [.001461, .000730]}).iloc[:, ::-1])` versus  `print(pd.DataFrame({'Word': ["('A',)", "('45',)"], '1_gram-Probability': [.001461, .000730]}).iloc[:, ::-1])`